# Small pool concerns

Tags: mining-pools

If my miner is connected to a small pool and my hash rate is 2k, when will I see a balance?  The pool hasn't found a block in a few months and I have been mining for a few weeks. The pay out is .3 and I should have reached that last week.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Small pools can be frustrating, but it's a part of the process. Until the pool finds a block no one gets paid. You've *earned* payment, but it won't *post* to you until that block is found and distributed proportionately to all those who have contributed effort to that block. That proportion on most Monero pools is your **Shares** statistic. Then, you have to meet the minimum withdrawal threshold to be able to transfer out. It's why small miners often gravitate to big pools, but I'd encourage you to be patient and keep with it.

There's actually an interesting mathematical benefit that can be argued about new/small pools. If they find that block on the near side of the probability curve, you in effect are granted more payment than the mean expectation especially if it happens outside 1σ. It's a short-term phenomenon and unlikely, but it happens.